# Encode all logs in Slf4j

Tags: java, slf4j

Is there any good way to custom logging to Slf4j

I wanted to ESAPI encode all logs before printing to console.Is there any better way to do it.

currently I use

```
log.info("This is my log {}", id);
```

is it possible to achieve with out using EsAPiLogger. It will be huge change to do in multiple places

I do not want to change the implementation in my code.

Any help on this

Comment: Have you set `LogEncodingRequired=true` ??

Comment: @VishwaRatna I wanted to use ESAPI for encoding, is there any way to do it

Comment: Slf4j is an interface, it does not do anything. So, the question is meaningless. Apparently you are using some implementation, e.g. logback or log4j, please find out and look for how to customise appenders.

Comment: How would the logs look then?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen , it is in encoded form. Quite people use it to prevent attacks.

Comment: Include the proper ESAPI jars with support for SLF4j, configure ESAPI and it should work. See https://javadoc.io/static/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.2.0.0/index.html?org/owasp/esapi/logging/slf4j/package-summary.html

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, can you share any example

Comment: Remove logback or whatever you are using and include the proper esapi jar that include those files. Should work immediatly. Make sure you use the latest version as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum ESAPI logging format is different right. SO this will change log.info("This is my log {}", id);

Comment: No it won't. ESAPI contains a SLF4j delegate/adapter.

Comment: @M.Deinum. Can you help me how to initialize logger

Comment: You don't need to . Just include the proper jars, the slf4j detecting mechanism will do the rest. Make sure you don't include things like logbakc, log4j(2) etc.